# Why does one python file have indent-tabs-mode set?

Tags: python, emacs

I've got one Python source file which has somehow "remembered" the wrong indent mode.  If I do "emacs foo.py", and then immediately do "c-h v indent-tabs-mode", it says, "Its value is t".  All other python source files come up with indent-tabs-mode nil.

I do not have any literal tabs in the file.  If I insert any new text, the indentation is done using tabs.  At some point in the past, I did save (and check into version control) a version of the file which had tabs in it.

I'm using python-mode.el, version 5.1.0, and GNU Emacs 23.3.1.  The file does open in Python mode.

What is going on here?  Where has emacs stored some bit of state saying to set indent-tabs-mode for just this one file, and how did it get set in the first place?

Comment: You can also specify local variable if you need: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html

Comment: I suggest you check your .emacs file to see if it sets `indent-tabs-mode` somewhere, maybe at top-level or within an `eval-after-load`.

Answer (score 3):

Check the source tree for any `.dir-locals.el` files. These may be overriding your default python-mode settings.

See the documentation on [Directory Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).

Answer (score -1):

OK, I think I figured this out.  There was no .dir-locals.el file, but I can reproduce the behavior.  Start with:

```
if foo:
        print "this line is indented with 8 spaces"
```

and save that into foo.py.  Open foo.py again, go to the end of the print line, and hit return to create and auto-indent another line.  That line gets indented with a tab!  I don't know how  I originally got the line indented with 8 spaces (I use 4 spaces for indents), but that seems to be what's causing this to happen.

Manually fixing up the 8-space indent to be 4 spaces and saving the file solved the problem.

I imagine tabnanny or pylint would have found this.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour. I guess there's some alchemy in your emacs config making this happen. :P